# Wifi, Lockscreen, Volume icon not visible in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweaks

After installing **Gnome extension like dash to dock and some themes and icons from gnome**. ubuntu ***wifi icon, lock screen, logout icon, user icon, Bluetooth icon*** **disappeared from the top bar as well as from the drop-down**.

[image: Icons are just disappeared]

Comment: "*some themes and icons*" are probably the culprits. Did you try changing them again?

Comment: yes but nothing happens, after applying the theme it was working fine but when I was trying to install dash to dock after that it is not showing

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include details of the icon pack and theme you're using.